# Buttons with a textarea on web page

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone please point me at a resource that shows how to add buttons to a textarea on a web page? Similar to Yahoo mail where an email address is turned into a button with a cross for removal.
In fact exactly how tags are added to the Tags textarea on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are very good jQuery plugins that accomplish this. One of them is [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) library. You can find examples on this page, as well as source code and [documentation](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown) on how to use it. You can always style it according to your needs through css.